# Apex Legends stuck at 60 FPS (G-Sync 144hz monitor)

Tags: framerate, apex-legends, nvidia-geforce-experience

With [+fps_max unlimited](https://www.dexerto.com/apex-legends/how-to-get-higher-fps-apex-legends-144-fps-cap-on-pc-342835) it still caps with the following behavior:

- On "Triple Buffered" FPS Locks caps at 60 & g-sync works
- On "Adaptive" FPS moves freely between 60-89 but monitor caps refreshes 60 
  *(my monitor says it's hardware refresh rate with hardware buttons & I see tearing)*
- On "Disabled" FPS is 240 and monitor caps at 60 and there's crazy tearing

Related:

https://www.reddit.com/r/apexlegends/comments/ansujz/3840x2160_issues_stuck_at_30fps/

https://www.reddit.com/r/apexlegends/comments/av9f6z/fps_stuck_at_60max_after_using_nvidia_inspector/

https://boards.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/help-support/MWAakW4Y-stuck-at-exactly-60fps-vsync-off-anti-aliasing-off-vsync-disabled-in-nvidea

Comment: Also, If you're using 'Fullscreen', make sure that the resolution setting doesn't also set the refresh rate to 60hz.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently Dynamic Super Resolutions conflict with the driver reporting max refresh rate to the game, *even if they are not in use*. **They MUST be disabled.**

Right click Desktop > nVidia Control Panel > Mange 3D Settings > DSR - Factors > Set to Off

Apex Legends > Settings > Video > VSync > Double Buffered

[image]

Other things I happen to also change before it worked, that I presume were unrelated: repairing the game. Removing & re-apply the Origin In Game FPS counter. Settings the game resolution to 1600x900

Comment: This seems to happen on GTX 1080 but not RTX 2080 Ti

Comment: This is also happening on a gigabyte3060 and not on an msi 3080